# Any issue in referencing a unique index from a foreign key table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key, unique-constraint

Is there any concern in referencing a unique index from a foreign key table?

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 9):

No, a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint can reference a column combination that is either the `PRIMARY KEY` or has a `UNIQUE` constraint or has a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Copied from MSDN page, [`CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx):

> `FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES`
>   Is a constraint that provides referential integrity for the data in the column or columns. `FOREIGN KEY` constraints require that each value in the column exists in the corresponding referenced column or columns in the referenced table. **`FOREIGN KEY` constraints can reference only columns that are `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraints in the referenced table or columns referenced in a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the referenced table.** Foreign keys on computed columns must also be marked `PERSISTED`.

The only difference between the first (primary key) option and the other two is that unique<sup>*</sup> constraints and indexes can be defined on nullable columns. Primary key columns have to be `NOT NULL`.

<sub>* Note that there are some slight differences between these in SQL-Server (unique indexes offer some options that are not available with unique constraints): [When should I use a unique constraint instead of a unique index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index)</sub>

<sub>For example, (as @gbn points), a unique index can be partial. But then, it can't be referenced by a FK.</sub>

Comment: Note: if the parent unique index is filtered, you can't use it for an FK. Minor point though