# Is there a performance penalty when there are two unique indexes on a table with all of the colums in one index are also in the other index?

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, unique-constraint

In my database I have a table with two indexes. There is one unique index #1 on columns a,b which I need for data integrity reasons. I have another index #2 with columns c,a,b that is used for performance reasons. I noticed this index #2 is also unique.

The uniqueness of index #2 seems to me to be redundant since you can't have duplicate values in index #2 without also having duplicate values in index #1. I am tempted to change index #2 so it is no longer unique, because I imagine the database engine might perform a second check on c,a,b in index #2 to ensure uniqueness on these columns every time a row is inserted, causing a performance hit, even though there can never be duplicate values. Is this correct?

Is there any way to delete the index #1 on a,b and keep the index #2 on c,a,b but still force a unique constraint on just columns a,b without maintaining two separate indexes? That would allow me to only have one index with all three columns but still enforce my data integrity constraint on a,b. I don't need an index on a,b for performance because all my select queries include column c in the where clause. Would this be a use case for a unique constraint instead of an index? I thought that the database engine basically treats these two constructs the same (see this post: [When should I use a unique constraint instead of a unique index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index)).

Keep in mind the indexes are not redundant, but the "uniqueness" of the indexes is redundant. Seems like it is a no-brainier to make index #2 non-unique. But does this result in any actual performance gain? Does the database check the uniqueness of both indexes even though the columns in index #1 are entirely included in index #2?

Some answers asked about example queries that are used to select data from this table. Here are the most common ones:

```
Select [some other columns] from table where c=1 and a=2
Select [some other columns] from table where c=1
Select [some other columns] from table where c=1 and a=2 and b=3
```

These queries typically include selecting lots of other columns not in any index.

What we typically never run is a query like this:

```
Select [stuff] from table where a=2 and b=3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The uniqueness of index #2 seems to me to be redundant since you can't have duplicate values in index #2 without also having duplicate values in index #1.

Yes, declaring index #2 *unique* is redundant. Index #1 needs to exist to support the foreign key, so there's little chance of it being dropped.

> I am tempted to change index #2 so it is no longer unique, because I imagine the database engine might perform a second check on c,a,b in index #2 to ensure uniqueness on these columns every time a row is inserted, causing a performance hit, even though there can never be duplicate values.

This is the wrong thing to focus on. SQL Server always needs to locate the insertion point. If it finds an existing row for the supplied key(s) and the index is marked unique, an error is raised. Otherwise, the new row is inserted at the correct point.

There is a much more important consequence of marking an index unique unnecessarily. Any update that changes one of the key columns requires special handling to avoid transient key violations during update processing. In SQL Server, this means extra *Split*, *Sort*, and *Collapse* operators and wide (per-index) maintenance for the affected index.

[image: Split/Sort/Collapse for unique index maintenance]

This is a lot more expensive that the issue you were concerned about.

> Is there any way to delete the index #1 on a,b and keep the index #2 on c,a,b but still force a unique constraint on just columns a,b without maintaining two separate indexes?

No.

> I don't need an index on a,b for performance because all my select queries include column c in the where clause.

The example queries suggest the equality predicate on column c alone is selective enough that the optimizer chooses a nonclustered index seek plus lookup plan. The optimizer is cautious about selecting this type of plan, which implies column c is very selective indeed (or estimates are poor).

Since you're retrieving columns outside the index anyway, you might well find a nonclustered *non-unique* index on column c alone is sufficient.

Adding a and/or b to the index key would be useful if enough queries benefit from the more precise index seek to justify the extra space and maintenance. Only you have enough information to make this judgement call.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server keeps indexes synchronised with base table data. When a row is inserted into a table it is also added to all relevant indexes.

Indexes are ordered. So the the new row must be added to the correct place in each index. Having found the correct place to add the new row it is trivial to see if there is an existing value in that place. The overhead to check uniqueness is trivial.

Yes, during inserts there is an overhead to having multiple indexes on the table. But this is due to there being multiple indexes which must be kept consistent with the table. It has nothing to do with the indexes being unique or not.

There can be many benefits to having overlapping indexes when reading data. Grant's answer covers this. The balance between overhead and benefit will vary depending on your workload.

If an index is unique it is good to declare it as such. The query optimizer uses that information when constructing query plans. With both indexes declared as unique the optimizer is more likely to come up with better plans on average than it would otherwise. Give the optimizer as much information as you can about your data to help it do its job.

There is no way to declare a subset of index columns as unique and redundant to a (part of) another index.

Answer (score 3):

So, those are two different indexes, with different key structures. Yes, #1, on A,B, is replicated within #2, but, the addition of the column C means that it also must be unique, combined with A&B. That is not a duplicate of the behavior of Index #1. It's separate and different.

If, it was set up #1 is A,B and #2 is A,B,C, then, #1 would be a redundant index, possibly not needed. However, even here, caution has to take part. Because, #1 in this scenario is smaller than #2. So, a scan of #1 could be faster than a scan of #2, depending. In that case, #1 is used for some queries, even though it's a duplicate of #2.

Also, when different columns are the first column in an index, they result in different histograms within the statistics. Those different histograms could be useful to different queries. Hence, a unique index on columns A,B might support different queries than a unique index on columns B, A. Even though, from a logical standpoint, these are the same indexes.

Testing your queries to understand how the indexes are used is important. Monitoring performance over time is also important. Then, when you do find a legitimate duplicate index, you can tell if dropping it is neutral to performance, helps performance, or hurts performance. Because simply looking at the index and its structure, won't tell you how it's used in the system.

EDIT:
Forgot to include this. Of course, there is overhead to maintenance, possibly even blocking & resource contention, with having too many indexes. This is why eliminating duplicate indexes is important. I'm not saying you shouldn't eliminate duplicates. Just that you need to be really clear about what constitutes a duplicate (which you don't have in this case), and whether or not that duplicate exists for other purposes.

Comment: I don't understand this part of your answer:
  Yes, #1, on A,B, is replicated within #2, but, the addition of the column C means that it also must be unique, combined with A&B.
I need A,B to be unique, and that means there can't be any duplicate rows with A,B,C because A,B has to be unique.

Comment: If I understand the second half of your answer correctly, it might make sense to have both indexes, even if I never run a query with just a,b (without c) because there could be cases where, based on the data in the table, the optimizer would use index #1 instead of index #2 even though column c is included in the where clause, because column c is in the wrong place in the index for that query. In this case would it make sense to ensure the order of the columns in index #2 is based on how many different values are in the table for each column?

Comment: It really does come down to testing. The only sure duplicate is when the order is the same too. A, B and A, B, C would be considered duplicates. While A, B and B, A, C, or C, A, B, or C, B, A, would not because of the order change. It's a common practice to do this because of the behavior of the optimizer.

Comment: But!!! You still have to ensure that those indexes are getting used. I remember a situation once, not one I did, where the person put an index on every column, and then on every permutation of combinations of columns in every possible order (something like 56 indexes on one table). But about 53 of those indexes were never used. And they did this across an entire database. It's a nightmare.